# IE7 z-index issue with a covering div

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have this (simplified) DOM on my page:

```
<div id="Cover" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="body">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="controlContainer">
            <div id="FirstSelectorContainer">
                <div id="FirstLink"><a href="/scriptlessfallback">Open Link</a></div>
                <div id="FirstLinkChoice"><a href="/test">I should be clickable</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`#Cover` Has this CSS:

```
#Cover
{
    background-color: white;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
    -moz-opacity: 0.50;
    z-index: 600;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

`#FirstLinkChoice` has this CSS:

```
#FirstLinkChoice
{
    width: 616px;
    height: 77px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 144px;
    border: 1px solid #424242;
    z-index: 800;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}
```

This script adds a click event to `#FirstLink`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#FirstLink").length) {
        $("#FirstLink").click(function () { $("#FirstLinkChoice").show(); dimOn(); return false; });
    }
});
```

(dimOn, just activates the cover using the CSS `display` property.)

The desired outcome is when someone clicks `#FirstLink` the cover goes over the page and the contents of `#FirstLinkChoice` are available for selection.

This seems to work fine for all browsers except for IE7, which puts `#Cover` over the entire page including `#FirstLinkChoice` despite the z-index being lower.

What do I need to change to get this working in IE7? Unfortunately I am stuck with this nesting structure in production.

I'm perfectly OK with a solution that is Javascript based (without javascript, the link will fall back to a page with similar info to the pop up) or special CSS just for IE7 as I will use a conditional stylesheet.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Boaz not without changing the DOM, which isn't possible.

Comment: I see I missed the key requirement .

Comment: My closest kludge is to add a second cover div inside `#FirstSelectorContainer` and instead of the CSS targeting `#Cover` change it to `.cover` and show both in `dimOn()`

Answer (score 0):

Nesting `#FirstLinkChoice` inside the element `.body` that is supposed to be overlaid by `#Cover` is likely the cause. Try placing `#FirstLinkChoice` outside `.body`.

For example:

```
<div id="Cover" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="FirstLinkChoice"><a href="/test">I should be clickable</a></div>
<div class="body">
    ...
</div>
```